# C - segmentation fault in while loop with pointer

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop

I am getting segmentation fault in my while loop but I don't know why.

[image]

Comment: 1) Post code as text, not pictures of text 2) Don't post links to pictures 3) There's not nearly enough code shown to know what the problem is.  Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: How are you allocating or declaring memory?

Comment: we'll need to see more of your code, rather than just the looping part, like, how you're allocating memory, where else you are using the allocated memory, etc. And try to post the code itself instead of pictures of code fragments, not that it makes a difference to the problem, just that it would be easier for us to copy it and reproduce the error.

Comment: See [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and talk to the duck... Really, it helps `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code:

```
while (temp->next != NULL)
{
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

So - what happens when `temp` starts as, or becomes NULL?  Say at the end of the linked list.

The answer - your while loop condition is checking `NULL->next`, which is a memory violation, because your program (probably) doesn't own the memory at, say address 0x00000008 (NULL is zero, and `->` creates a memory offset when it's compiled).

How about:

```
while (temp != NULL)
{
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

Comment: Almost, but not quite. The problem only occurs when `temp` is NULL to begin with. If `temp` isn't NULL initially, then `temp->next != NULL` will return false before setting `temp` equal to NULL.